# Call async method in portable code library from windows runtime component

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, portable-class-library, winrt-async

## Background

I am building an app that will be available on both Windows 8 (as a store app) and Windows 7 (as a WPF desktop app). These apps will allows browsing a bunch (some 500+ application "pages") of content.

While I cannot share much of the code between them, I do want to share as much as possible. So I have created a Portable Code Library (PCL) targeting .NET 4.5, Silverlight 4+, and Windows 8. Since the Win 8 app is written in JavaScript (for various reasons, not part of this question), I also have a Windows Runtime Component which acts as a proxy between the JavaScript and PCL. In other words, async calls from JavaScript first invoke a method on the WinRT component, which then calls the corresponding method in the PCL.

## Problem

In order to support async operations in the PCL, I installed the Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Bcl.Async packages via NuGet.  These, among other things, defind the Task and Task<> classes necessary to async methods, but they do so in their own assemblies. The WinRT component does not need those libraries as Task and Task<> are already defined for it.  The problem is when I add code in the WinRT component to call an Async method in the PCL that returns a Task<> object, I get the following build error:

> WINMDEXP : error WME1007: Could not resolve reference 'Assembly(Name=System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)'.

## What I Have Tried

I have tried lots of things, but the main two that might come up are:

1. Modifying the app.Config for the WinRT component to add a bindingRedirect for the assembly.
2. Making the PCL call externally non-async by getting the Task object back from the async call it does internally and calling Wait() on it.  The Wait either never returns to throws a cryptic exception.

So, any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Dave Parker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with WinMDExp which has been fixed in Visual Studio 2013.

We've provided a workaround on this page (see Issue 7): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx.

Answer (score -1):

Windows Runtime Components are special types of projects targeting subset of Windows Runtime available for Windows Store apps written in JavaScript, C# and C++. and they also require specific types of classes and properties in it like all public classes to be sealed, no public fields, no public methods returning Task, only IAsyncAction or IAsyncOperation...
You can refrence your Portable Class Libraries in it, but with some limitations.

**Edited**: To fix your problem you must not return in your Windows Runtime Component any non-WinRT types - you cannot return any types from the Portable Library, you have to create wrapper types.
You also cannot return Task and Task types because these are not WinRT types, but you can create wrapper methods and return the proper awaitable types like this:

```cs
public IAsyncAction DoActionAsync()
{
    return DoAsync().AsAsyncAction();
}

internal async Task DoAsync()
{
}

public IAsyncOperation<int> DoIntOperationAsync()
{
    return DoIntAsync().AsAsyncOperation();
}

internal async Task<int> DoIntAsync()
{
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: Actually Windows Runtime Components can reference PCLs just fine. I am already doing so.

Comment: You're right, you can reference Portable libs with some limitations, but not everywhere. In Background Tasks you must use only pure Windows Runtime Components.

Comment: Either I am misunderstanding your response or you misunderstood my question. My issue is not _returning from_ the WRC, but _calling to_ an async method in the PCL from the WRC. In the PCL, Task<> is implemented by the Microsoft.Bcl.* libraries from CodePlex. In a WRC Task<> is built-in to the WinRT subset of the .NET Framework. The compiler cannot cast them to any common base. Furthermore, IAsynAction and IAsyncOperation are defined in the Windows.Foundation namespace (part of WinRT), and thus not available for use in the PCL. If your response somehow addresses this, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, I've reproduced your scenario and it looks like Portable Libs with Microsoft.Bcl.Async cannot be used in Windows Runtime Components, yet :( This should be probably logged on Microsoft Connect Site as a bug.

Comment: I have submitted a "contact" form to the package owners on the NuGet site. That seems the most direct way to reach the people responsible for the package(s). The closest bucket I could find on connect.microsoft.com was "Visual Studio and the .NET Framework", which is a very big team (I used to work in that group).

Comment: This is due to a bug in WinMDExp, the workaround is given in another answer.